# Why error evaluating expression in subreport is thrown?

Tags: jasper-reports

There ist three Jasper Reports  include each other. All of this works fine in iReport Designer 5.6.0  and in TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio 6.9.0 - Visual Designer for JasperReports 6.9.0. 
But in Java Application  (WebbApp) with

```
<groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
<artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
<version>6.8.1</version>
```

not, with following Error

01:52:47.704 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport - Fill 1: exception
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.handleEvaluationException(JREvaluator.java:284)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:316)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:672)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:640)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1169)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:522)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:350)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:383)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:548)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2583)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:813)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:264)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:615)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:433)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:818)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:61)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JREmptyDataSource
    at reportGroup_1565043926314_683208.evaluate(reportGroup_1565043926314_683208:218)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:302)
    ... 19 common frames omitted

Actually everything is very simple

reportA  has reportGroup as subReport.
reportGroup has reportPosition as subReport.

if there is no DS Expression definded for reportPosition ... it works in Java, (without Data ofcource)

```
     <subreport>
        <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="555" height="42" uuid="5b11fe21-104d-41b0-8e35-7612df9ac9c3"/>
        <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
           <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
        </subreportParameter>
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/group/group")]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "reportGroup.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
     </subreport>
```

```
     <subreport>
        <reportElement x="0" y="33" width="555" height="38" uuid="ec08d032-8cde-4a66-9bd8-bb0e82c55731"/>
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/group/position")]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "reportPosition.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
     </subreport>
```

Comment: Just to exclude errors of selection /group/position   I tried following DS Expression  : 

new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()  

with following result : 
Error evaluating expression for source text: new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()

looks like Error in jasper file or not ?  Why one Jasper-File set works in iReport and Jasper Studio and does not work in JavaApp with Jasper Libs ???

Comment: https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1141426/problem-passing-datasource-one-subreport-another-subreport

Comment: looks like Error in jasper file or not ?  Whay same Jasper-File (I copy jasper files to webapp, and do not compile it in javaapp..  I tried to do that, without success) set works in iReport and Jasper Studio and does not work in JavaApp with Jasper Libs ?